# Overcome the 1000 lines limit in Results on Nuxeo shell

Tags: nuxeo, nuxeo-js-client

in order to access a nuxeo installation i am using nuxeo shell and run a query

```
query -uid "SELECT * FROM Document where dc:created > DATE '2022-03-10' and ecm:path STARTSWITH '/default-domain/workspaces/Patricia/Documents' and ecm:primaryType <> 'Folder'  AND ecm:currentLifeCycleState != 'deleted'"
```

i do get results, but they are limited to 1000 rows.

How do i raise or eliminate this limit ?
Or alternatively, how can i run a query in Nuxeo's UI so i can export a list of uid ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Nuxeo paginates the result, whether you want or not. You could bump up the `nuxeo.pageprovider.default-max-page-size` (which is set to 1000 by default) but the only real solution is to use multiple calls, each time increasing the `currentPageIndex` until you are not getting any more results.

As no such option is [documented](https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/nuxeo-server-commands/#query) for the Nuxeo shell query command, I doubt it is possible there. So you would need to call the API directly or use one of the Nuxeo clients (e.g. Python, JavaScript)

In Python I did it like this:

```python
def query_paged(nx, query):
    index = 0
    while True:
        query_result = nx.documents.query({"query": query, "currentPageIndex": index})
        page = query_result["entries"]
        if page > 0:
            for entry in page:
                yield entry
        else:
            break
        index += 1
```